# What are some CSS bugs in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've found some references to bugs or issues in IE's interpretation of CSS, but the information seems rather scattered. I'd like to have a pointer to a comprehensive overview, if such an overview exists.

**edit:** it's already something that Microsoft is willing to list IE's CSS problems (thanks mouviciel->sanchothefat), but they're not going to offer workarounds, obviously. So workarounds would be nice too.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I find the best policy to avoid pain is to follow these rules:

1. Build in a more-compliant and developer-friendly browser like firefox first, test thoroughly in IE (and safari/chrome(webkit) and opera) later
2. Use a strict doctype- avoid quirks mode, since quirks are by definition not standard
3. Use a [reset style sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/is-it-ok-to-use-a-css-reset-stylesheet)
4. Use a javascript framework like jQuery or Prototype - they can hide some javascript and DOM incompatibilities.
5. Use good semantic layout- it's more likely to degrade nicely for a mis-behaving browser
6. Accept that it won't be perfect and don't sweat the really small variances

Follow those rules I don't have as many problems in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

Check out [Quirks Mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html). It is a great resource for CSS compatibility across browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Me, I use the "[Internet Explorer Exposed](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html)". Very in-depth resource.

Answer (score 1):

I find myself constantly referring to this page:

http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/internet-explorer.shtml

Answer (score 1):

You may find some answers by consulting this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495050/list-of-css-features-not-supported-by-ie6).

Answer (score 1):

For dropdownlists:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    ...
    <option value="N">N</option>
</select>
```

CSS border styles do not work:

If you'll try:

```
select
{
    border: solid 1px #0000ff;
}
```

nothing will happen.

Also a submit button will expand its width proportionally to the button text, until you give it the style:

```
input[type="submit"]
{
overflow:visible;
}
```

As well as many other funny things. :)

Comment: @dfa: Just checked it again, everything is working, in both IE8 and compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

I swear by [PositionIsEverything](http://positioniseverything.net/).

They maintain a list of bugs/oddities in most browsers.  Check out their exhaustive list of [Internet Explorer bugs](http://positioniseverything.net/explorer.html), I hope you find it comprehensive enough.

Answer (score 0):

[quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org) has already been posted, but I'll add [On having layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html), which explains one of the principles underlying many of IE's oddities.