# Fix layout via css

Tags: css, internet-explorer, layout

I've got a layout bug that shows up in IE6, and **I'm trying to come up with a way to give some clues to this content in our content area so that it won't drop down below the navigation menu.** Sadly, while this would probably be relatively easy to fix if I could redesign the whole page, I can't do that...it's a live site that hosts many, many content pages...and it only breaks in in a couple places, in IE6, in some somewhat unusual circumstances...so taking the risk of a major layout change for the content holder isn't really reasonable.

The layout is supposed to look something like this:

```
+-------+ +-------------------+
| Menu  | | Content chunk 1   |
|       | +-------------------+
|       | +-------------------+
+-------+ | Content chunk 2   |
          +-------------------+
            Footer
```

But in IE 6, it looks like:

```
+-------+ 
| Menu  | 
|       | 
|       | 
+-------+ 
+-------------------+ 
| Content chunk 1   |
+-------------------+
+-------------------+ 
| Content chunk 2   |
+-------------------+
            Footer
```

I've been looking at trying to fix this and am going through some of the references suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83696/strategy-for-fixing-layout-bugs-in-ie6), but I'm hoping a css guru might be able to easily see some light that I am not.

The code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//Dtd Xhtml 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/Dtd/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<body>
<div style="margin: 11px auto; width: 775px">

    <!-- Menu -->
    <div style="width:160px; float:left; clear:left; border:#999 1px dashed;">
        Menu Item 1<br />
        Menu Item 2<br />
    </div>

    <!-- Main content area -->
    <div style="position: relative; width: 565px; float: left; margin-right: -222px">

        <!-- I'm able to start modifying here. -->
        <!-- Content chunk 1 -->
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>This is data chunk 1 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell</td>
                <td>This is data chunk 2 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell</td>
                <td>This is data chunk 3 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell</td>
                <td>This is data chunk 4 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell</td>
                <td>This is data chunk 5 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <!-- I'd like to be able to stop modifying here. -->

        <!-- Content chunk 2 -->
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>This is data chunk 1</td>
                <td>This is data chunk 2</td>
                <td>This is data chunk 3</td>
                <td>This is data chunk 4</td>
                <td>This is data chunk 5</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <!-- I have to stop modifying here. -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div style="float: clear; text-align: center;">
        Here's a footer of some kind.  I don't want to be overlapped.
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As an aside, I know the css style statements in the areas surrounding the content area aren't ideal.  I didn't code them, I just have to deal with them.

I haven't had much luck yet...but I also know that css is *not* where my expertise resides.

Suggestions?  Or is it hopeless?

**EDIT:** I've made some modifications to this question to try to improve clarity...hopefully get rid of a downvote or two.  Many thanks to those of you that have already responded...I'm going to start going through those responses now to evaluate them.

Comment: Someone down voted the quesiton. its a reasonable question however the description of wha tis actually going wrong is very weak, try adding more detail, possible a link to an screen shot.

Comment: Okay...thanks for the heads up.  I'll see if I can't clarify the nature of the problem a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any way of correcting this using only CSS. IE6's wrapping calculation is going to be preformed in such a way that unless the main content area is expanded, the content will be moved under the menu. I don't know if this will work within your constraints, but a bit of code like this will correct it visually.

```
function resize_content ( )
{
     var main = document.getElementById ( "main" );
     var content = document.getElementById ( "content" );
     if ( main && content )
          main.style["width"] = ( content.clientWidth + 160 ) + "px";
}
```

I used IDs for clarity, but if you couldn't modify the markup, you could get the elements using relatives.

Comment: Actually I do have IDs...I just removed them in the sample, trying to pare the sample down to the critical essentials.  Thanks!

Comment: This answer is incredibly sweet (or as sweet as a hack to an ugly system can be.)

Comment: Thanks! I agree; it's not the prettiest solution -- but you sounded like you're pretty limited (and I know how that is)

Answer (score 3):

if you can wrap the offending table in another block level element such as a div tag you can style that div as below:

```
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: scroll;">
  <table border="1">
      <tr>
          <td>This is data chunk 1 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell</td>
          <td>This is data chunk 2 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell</td>
          <td>This is data chunk 3 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell</td>
          <td>This is data chunk 4 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell</td>
          <td>This is data chunk 5 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell</td>
       </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

This will put the table into a scrollable window so it won't stretch the div past 565 pixels. This, of course, will only work for you if making the table scrollable is an option with your client. Unfortunately you don't have many other options.

Comment: I'd recommend changing this to `overflow-x: scroll` instead, but this is a very nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's hopeless if you can't get to the 565px div, because that's what's not positioning itself inline with the menu...

Here's something you could do with JS:

```
    <!-- I'm able to start modifying here. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('table#firstTable').parent().parent('div').removeAttr('style').attr('style', 'margin: 11px auto;');
        });
    </script>
```

First you get rid of the hard-coded style on the DIV, then add back whatever you want to stay there. Pretty clumsy, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: nah, he could go with an !important selector to override what he needs to or even JS if it comes to that

Comment: by the way, it will work if you remove width: 775px, since it is making the 565px div jump down because it doesn't fit in on one line with the menu because of additional width due to borders (160 + 565 + borders does not equal 775).

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the solution you're looking for, but a possible alternative would be to change the text itself and add a hover to display the whole thing...  eg:

<td><span title="This is data chunk 1 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell">This is data chunk1 with...</span></td>

Answer (score 1):

There simply isn't a solution which you'll both like and be allowed to implement. The incorrectly-cased `DOCTYPE` ("Dtd Xhtml") throws IE6 into quirks mode, from which there is no return. Specifically, in quirks mode there is **absolutely no way** to force IE6 to not "stretch" elements, which breaks your floating. You can cause it to appear (still stretched) on the same "line" as your float if you can get access to the "main content" `div`, but aside from that, you'll simply have to munge the contents, by adding spaces or `<wbr>`s:

```
<!-- this works, but would be hard to implement programmatically -->
<td>This is data chunk 1 with<wbr>A<wbr>Long<wbr>Chunk<wbr>That<wbr>Doesn't<wbr>Divide<wbr>Well</td>
<td>This is data chunk 2 with<wbr>A<wbr>Long<wbr>Chunk<wbr>That<wbr>Doesn't<wbr>Divide<wbr>Well</td>
<td>This is data chunk 3 with<wbr>A<wbr>Long<wbr>Chunk<wbr>That<wbr>Doesn't<wbr>Divide<wbr>Well</td>
<td>This is data chunk 4 with<wbr>A<wbr>Long<wbr>Chunk<wbr>That<wbr>Doesn't<wbr>Divide<wbr>Well</td>
<td>This is data chunk 5 with<wbr>A<wbr>Long<wbr>Chunk<wbr>That<wbr>Doesn't<wbr>Divide<wbr>Well</td>
```

Comment: "The transitional DOCTYPE throws IE6 into quirks mode..."
Only when the DOCTYPE is not the first statement on the page - not in this case.

Comment: You're right — I think it's the incorrect casing, then, not the transitional DTD, that's throwing IE into quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I think you're looking for something similar to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//Dtd Xhtml 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/Dtd/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<body>
<div style="margin: 11px auto; width: 775px; position: relative">

    <!-- Menu -->
    <div style="position: absolute; width:160px; left: 0; top: 0; border:#999 1px dashed;">
            Menu Item 1<br />
            Menu Item 2<br />
    </div>

    <!-- Main content area -->
    <div style="margin-left: 165px">

            <!-- I'm able to start modifying here. -->
            <!-- Content chunk 1 -->
            <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                            <td>This is data chunk 1 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell</td>
                            <td>This is data chunk 2 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell</td>
                            <td>This is data chunk 3 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell</td>
                            <td>This is data chunk 4 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell</td>
                            <td>This is data chunk 5 withALongChunkThatDoesn'tDivideWell</td>
                    </tr>
            </table>

            <!-- I'd like to be able to stop modifying here. -->

            <!-- Content chunk 2 -->
            <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                            <td>This is data chunk 1</td>
                            <td>This is data chunk 2</td>
                            <td>This is data chunk 3</td>
                            <td>This is data chunk 4</td>
                            <td>This is data chunk 5</td>
                    </tr>
            </table>

            <!-- I have to stop modifying here. -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div style="float: clear; text-align: center;">
            Here's a footer of some kind.  I don't want to be overlapped.
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The above CSS does the following: Makes the outer div relative positioned, which allows you to then take the menu div and position it absolutely to its top left. Then, a left margin of 165px was put on the left of the content. Any content that doesn't fit in the content's space should overflow off to the right. I don't have any way to test in IE 6, the this works in Safari and should in Firefox.

Comment: Ahh..but unfortunately, that's in the area I can't modify.  I'm not really able to modify anything outside of the content area (including the content container), since that has the potential to affect *everything* on the site.